# SpringBoot RestController with @RequestParam and JQuery $.get()

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, thymeleaf

I want to make my little project and build Library app with API on Java and UI with ThymeLeaf and JQuery. Here is my controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/books-genre")
    public List<BookDto> findBooksByGenre(@RequestParam(name = "genre2") String genre) {
        System.err.println(genre);
        List<Book> books = BookService.findBooksByGenre(genre);
        return bookDtoConverter.booksToDto(books);
    }
```

Here is my UI in AJAx.

```
<script>
    function findBooksByGenre () {
        var x = document.getElementById("genre").value;
        console.log(x);
        var param = $.param(genre, x);
        var param2 = {
          genre : x
        };
        $.getJSON('/books-genre/' + $('#genre2').val()).done(function (books2) {
            alert(books2.length);
            books2.forEach(function (book2) {
                coment = book2.comments.length;
                cond = coment != 0 ? coment : 'no comments';
                $('tbody').append(`
                    <tr>
                        <td>${book2.id}</td>
                        <td>${book2.name}</td>
                        <td>${book2.author.name}</td>
                        <td>${book2.genre.name}</td>
                        <td> ${cond}
                        <a href="comments/?bookId=${book2.id}">view</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                `)
            });
        })
    };
</script>


<div class="a">
    <h2>Options</h2>
    <form action="">
        <label for="genre">Choose by genre: </label>
        <input type="text" id="genre"/>
        <input type="submit" onclick="findBooksByGenre()" value="Submit"><br><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to make a table with this books. But every my call do nothing! As if getJSON does not see my query params at all! I try another functions too, for example just `get(/books-genre, {genre2 : drama}).done()......`  nothing change. Please Help me say me what I do wrong.... Because another controller without query params works good

[It is a screenshot of my request which i try to call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye8Rv.png)

enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxUis.png)

Comment: I suggest you do the following:   Copy/Paste your Request from the developer tools on your browser, go to --> Network Tab, make your request, so we can see the complete call you are making.

See what the HttpStatus code is, and see if you get any exceptions at all.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye8Rv.png - it is a screenshot of my request which i try to call

Comment: The picture.....shows that it is working for you??? The genre2 you are passing is drama....the book you are returning has a genre of drama... I dont get what is Not working for you...

Comment: Excuse me I dont understand what is the trailing slash i should remove ?

Comment: It is not working when i push submit button. Nothing is happen. It is working only when i manually print url with query but not in my UI with AJAX function

Comment: The problem is that I failed to connect my controller method with AJAX function

Comment: Please open your browser developer toolbar again, and this time please provide the request URL + status screen shot, when you push the button.  Please dont manually put the URL in the browser.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye8Rv.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxUis.png